# weird iostream compile errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, iostream

I get these errors when trying to do the following.
I have a FileMgr class to handle an input and an output file with two member functions to copy each line of input into a list and to write to the output from each member of a list. note: the following functions work properly when handled directly by my main! so don't bother trying to make out what I'm doing with the copy functions, I spent a lot of time figuring them out and now they work fine, the problem is not there.

```
    FileMgr::FileMgr(string inFilename, string outFilename)
{
    input.open(inFilename);
    output.open(outFilename);
}

bool FileMgr::writeFileToList(list<string> &l)
{
    // copy each line of file into new member of list<string>
    if(!input.is_open())
        return false;

    copy(istream_iterator<string>(input), istream_iterator<string>(), back_inserter(l));

    return true;
}

bool FileMgr::writeListToFile(list<string>::iterator begin, list<string>::iterator end)
{
    // copy each member of list<string> in output file, beginning and ending at iterators begin, end
    // note that I have to pass a "false" end iterator, that is, end--, for it to work
    if(!output.is_open())
        return false;

    copy(begin, end, ostream_iterator<string>(output, "\n"));

    return true;
}
```

and up to here everything is fine. then my other class, which gets the list from FileMgr, and it's supposed to let the user edit it (im not there yet because of these errors), so heres part of my declaration:

```
class Dictionary
{
public:
    Dictionary(string inFileName = "dictionary.txt", string outFileName = "output.txt");
    void userEditor();
//private:
    list<string> dictionary;
    FileMgr manager;
    bool findWord(string word);
    bool addWord(string word);
    bool deleteWord(string word);
    void sortAndFix();
    void saveAndExit();
```

and here's my definitions so far, which is basically just the constructor:

```
    Dictionary::Dictionary(string inFileName, string outFileName)
{
    // open files and copy to list; sort and fix list.
    manager = FileMgr(inFileName, outFileName);

    dictionary.push_back(" ");
    if( manager.writeFileToList(dictionary) )
        cout << "File successfully read from " << inFileName << endl;
    else
        cout << "Error in reading " << inFileName << endl;

    sortAndFix();
}
```

when I compile, I get these errors somewhere unknown in the constructor just shown (because it's the only code in the file I get these errors from when compiling):

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(860): error 

C2249: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::operator =' : no accessible path to private member declared in virtual base 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ios(177) : see declaration of 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::operator ='
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator =(const std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(604): error C2249: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::operator =' : no accessible path to private member declared in virtual base 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ios(177) : see declaration of 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::operator ='
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator =(const std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
```

I can't understand what's wrong. my FileMgr works fine when tested from my main, so why would the compiler trip like that when working with FileMgr from another class??

Comment: Your error message suggests that you are doing something wrong with the `input` variable, so you may want to post that code too. Also see answer below. If I end up being right about this, your question may need a new title :)

Comment: Find out which line causes the last two errors because these errors seems to have nothing to do with your `writeFileToList` function.

Comment: let me edit my question so I show more code.

Comment: done editing, I still can't understand these errors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your problem is in this line:

```
manager = FileMgr(inFileName, outFileName);
```

From your code in `FileMgr` it seems that `FileMgr` has a stream `input` as a data member.  When you execute the above line, you'll invoke the assignment operator for `FileMgr`, which by default will try to copy all of the data members one at a time.  However, the copy functions for streams are not accessible (they're marked `private` and not implemented).  The errors you're getting are almost certainly due to the C++ compiler noticing that it needs to copy the streams, but failing to do so because the copy functions are inaccessible.

To change this, try initializing `manager` in the constructor's member initializer list:

```
Dictionary::Dictionary(string inFileName, string outFileName) 
    : manager(inFileName, outFileName) {
    /* ... */
}
```

This will initialize `manager` with the given parameters rather than trying to *assign* `manager` an object with the right parameters.

Hope this helps!

Comment: is what you said the same of doing FileMgr manager(inFileName, outFileName); inside the constructor? because apparently this compiles, but I thought I could not declare manager twice (since i'm declaring it already in the class declaration. So why can this compile at all? isn't it like having int a; in the declaration; then in the constructor you do int a = 3; but isn't a already defined? that's why I was doing it the other way. but thanks, it seems to work (but I wanna know why :) )

Comment: This is *similar* to doing that, but they have completely different behavior.  The initialization list is used to construct data members before the constructor starts running.  It will construct `manager` as though you had declared it `FileMgr manager(inFileName, outFileName)`.  However, if you just wrote out `FileMgr manager(inFileName, outFileName)`, the compiler would interpret it as creating a local variable with no connection to the data member.  In general, you'll want to use the initializer list to set up complex data members rather than assigning them values in the constructor.

Comment: oh ok. I didn't know that about the initializer list, i thought it was just a shortcut. still, how can the compiler let me declare a local variable with the same name and type of a member variable? i thought that was not possible

Answer (score 1):

```
bool FileMgr::writeFileToList(list<string> &l);
```

`FileMgr::writeFileToList` receive an argument of type `list<string>` by reference.

So you should actually do -

```
list<string> dictionary;
if( manager.writeFileToList(&dictionary) )
                            ^ error. You should not use & symbol here.
```

The argument type is not `list<string>*l` to send an address.

Comment: yes, that's part 2 of my question. i get those two errors when i do that!

Comment: What does the third argument of `copy(...);` do ? ( i.e., `inserter(l, l.end())` ) . Also you are sending a list whose size is **0**.

Comment: i'm using back_inserter(l) now as suggested by nawaz. im just copying input into l, but i still get that error

Comment: If your intention is to copy each line in the file to the list, I think `getline` and then performing a `push_back` until `EOF` is rather easy.

Comment: yes, that's what i used before, it works fine both ways. it's the call errors i don't get

Answer (score 1):

Just write:

```
if( manager.writeFileToList(dictionary) );
```

`&` is not needed. In fact, that causes the error!

BTW, your `std::copy` is incorrectly written. Here is the correct one:

```
copy(istream_iterator<string>(input), istream_iterator<string>(), std::back_inserter(l));
```

Note the last argument. It's `std::back_inserter(l)`.

Comment: yes, that's part 2 of my question. i get those two errors when i do that!

Comment: @Edoz: That means, there is problem with some other part of your code which you didn't post here!

Comment: ok! how do i know where it is then? stupid visual studio points me to lines in the header files, and doesn't even tell me where in my code the error happened (what i posted is the only errors i get)

Comment: @Edoz: Comment the `copy` in the function `writeFileToList`, and try compiling. Let me know if it compiles. If it compiles, then that would mean you've written `copy` incorrectly!

Comment: @Mahesh: Yes. I know that. I just didn't prefix it with `std::`.

Comment: turns out the error is not in copy, nor in the writetolist call. it's in my constructor, see edit once i'm done editing

Comment: haha ok. but now check out my edited question cause I really can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

`if( manager.writeFileToList(&dictionary) )` should be changed to

`if( manager.writeFileToList(dictionary) )`

Note you cant convert `Type*` to `Type&`

Comment: yes, that's part 2 of my question. i get those two errors when i do that!